# Why can my C++ application not find my C# plugin in the plugin folder?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, c++-cli

**The Application**

I have an application written in C++.

It lives in `C:\app\app.exe`

**Plugins**

The application can be extended using plugins. Plugins are DLLs written in C++. I do not have access to the source code for app.exe

Plugins live in `C:\app\plugins`

`app.exe` uses the Windows functions [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa)  and [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) to load the functions in the plugin DLLs (plugin DLLs and function names are specified by the user at run time).

**Generic Plugin**

There is a generic plugin that can run plugins written in C#. This generic plugin is structured like this

1. A C++ class called GenericPlugin. -> produces `GenericPlugin.dll` (unmanaged DLL)
2. A C++/CLI class called PluginLoader -> produces `PluginLoader.dll`
3. A C# class called Tools -> produces `Tools.dll` (managed DLL)

GenericPlugin calls PluginLoader which calls Tools.

Tools uses `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` and Reflection (to find all DLLs (e.g. `SomeDotNetPlugin.dll`) with static classes with methods with a custom attribute).

I have the source code for the plugins and can semi-debug these using Visual Studio 2019. I can only step through the C++ code. I cannot step through the C++/CLI or C# code.

So the folder/file structure looks like this

```
C:\app\app.exe
C:\app\plugins\GenereicPlugin.dll
C:\app\plugins\PluginLoader.dll
C:\app\plugins\Tools.dll
C:\app\plugins\SomeDotNetPlugin.dll
```

**Problem**

When I run `app.exe` the app crashes.

Using Windows [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon),

1. I can see that `app.exe` can finds `GenereicPlugin.dll` and `PluginLoader.dll` in the plugins folder.
2. But `app.exe` fails to find .NET `Tools.dll`. According to Process Monitor `app.exe` only looks in `C:\app` for `Tools.dll` but not in `C:\app\plugins`

As a test I placed `Tools.dll` and `SomeDotNetPlugin.dll` in `C:\apps`. The DLL is now found but `app.exe` still does not work. Process Monitor does not tell me what is wrong.

**Questions**

1. How can I diagnose this problem?
2. Why does `app.exe` not look in the plugins folder to find the .NET C# managed DLL?

---

**Code**
Here very briefly the calls used in app.exe and the plugins.

app.exe

```
LoadLibraryExA( libName, NULL,  0);
...
static_cast< void * >( ::GetProcAddress( library_, symbolName ) );
...
```

GenericPlugin.dll

```
auto functionList = PluginLoader::listNetFunctions();
```

PluginLoader.dll

```
auto functions = Tools::listFunctions();
```

Tools.dll

```
string DirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
var fi = di.GetFiles("plugins\\*.dll");

foreach (var f in fi) {

    var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(f.FullName);              
    var types = a.GetTypes();
    var dm = buildDelegateMap();

    foreach (var t in types)  {
        foreach (var m in t.GetMembers())  {
            var ea = m.GetCustomAttribute<CustomFunctionAttribute>();      
            var mi = m as MethodInfo;
            string methodSignature = getMethodSignatureString(mi);
            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(dm[getMethodSignatureString(mi)], mi);
            var fp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(d);
            ...
            //store fp in dictionary ea.Name -> fp
            ...
```

Comment: The pdb file has the debug info.  Normally when you debug with more than one project you add a reference to the debug folder in other projects so the pdb file is located and the source files are also located.

Comment: `Why does app.exe not look in the plugins folder to find the .NET C# managed DLL?` Show us the code that does this, otherwise how can we answer?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've added some code.

Comment: And `DirPath` is definitely correct? If you `Debug.WriteLine(DirPath);` and attach a debugger (or run [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)) does it show the correct path?

Comment: Yes, DirPath is correct. Thank you, I will try DebugView.

Comment: By design, the CLR looks for dependent assemblies in the GAC first, in the directory that contains the .exe next.  You need an app.exe.config file with a `<probing>` element or an AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler.  That the .exe file is not a .NET program does not matter.  Whether you can subscribe the event soon enough is not obvious so favor the config file.